# How can populate the pre-defined html with data using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, templates

I have the many ajax forms where i am adding rows of data uisng ajax.
Now the form is being submitted correctly but i am yet not able to find the good solution how to append the data which i have just inserted in datbaase.

I have two options

1. From the server i return the data filled with content and just append it.
2. Just return true or flase and have html template where i can fill the data using jquery and then append that data in the table row.

CI like the second solution but can someone please point me to the tutorial or link where i can see how its practically used

Comment: Whats the actual question. You can return true or false? or how to use template etc?

Comment: i want to know , how to use the template

Comment: Which templates you are using? Handlebars, Mustache, jQuery templates, Dust

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to Check from server side, if the insert SQL was correct, create a XML or JSON object as output.

the output should be for example in JSON:
`{name:"John", lastName:"Doe"}` etc...

the easiest way to do this is to stack the variables in an Array, the array would look like:
$data = array("name"=>"John", "lastName"=>"Doe");

Then do

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

And php will transform that array into an Json object.

---

Then on the Javascript just do append the data to each field, to access to the json objects:
first parse the return from the php file:

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
```

then data.name and data.lastName will contain the info